# How to add watchdog logging to organic groups

Tags: 7, hooks, organic-groups

I have a Drupal 7 site which makes use of the organic groups module. I would like to add helpful watchdog log messages when users are removed from a group. What are some options? hook_og_membership_delete does not seem to fire.